# Angular2 Router3 difference between wildcard and prefix matching

Tags: javascript, angular

With the following config, `/` goes to HomeComponent, but anything else gets redirected to `/somewhere`.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'prefix' },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/somewhere', pathMatch: 'prefix' },
  { path: '/somewhere', component: Somewhere, pathMatch: 'prefix' },
])
```

Come someone please simply and clearly explain how router3 matches paths? Why does `path: ''` as a redirect match anything, where as `path: ''` as a component will only match `/`?

thanks

Comment: `path: ''` will catch `/` and wildcard will catch anything which was not caught by previous paths example `/abc`

Answer (score 0):

```
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, 'pathMatch': 'prefix' },
```

will continue to search for child routes after `''` matches.

Wildcard routes just matches everything that didn't match with previous routes.

Comment: Thanks Gunter. Sorry, I've reworded my question several times, but it should now clearly show what I'm trying to ask.

So why does path: `''` as a redirect match anything, where as path: `''` as a component will only match `/`?

Comment: Uh, missed the redirect version. Interesting case. I'd expect it to redirect after the `''` matches instead of looking for matching child routes. So it should be work similar to `**` routes, except that `**` routes can have children.

Comment: Ok, so when in `prefix` mode, Angular will match that route, or any child routes as well, and `redirect` considers anything a child route (since it can't have children). Is that correct?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. `''` with `prefix` matches any route and then searches the child routes for further matches. In the end the full route has to match. This means there has to be a `''` with `pathMatch: 'full'` somewhere in the children other wise the router will end up with no matching route for this path. With `**` any route just matches, no matter if there are child routes or not. I haven't actually tried `**` with child routes but I think to remember seeing that.

Comment: Does `pathMatch` have any affect on non-redirect routes, or is it only relevant for redirect routes? I'm still very confused by it...

Comment: It **does** have an effect on non-redirect routes as well. With `full` the router doesn't look for further child routes. The first `path: '', pathMatch: 'full'` ends the route matching algorithm while with `prefix`, it continues to search for child routes with the remaining `''` path because none of the path was consumed by the match.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126845/discussion-between-jon-and-gunter-zochbauer).